# PHP exit out of the current script

Tags: php, html, exit, die

How can I exit out of the current php script?

*For example:*

page.php

```
<?php
    include('./other-page.php');
?>
<h4>this text always shows</h4>
```

other-page.php

```
<?php
    if($_GET['v'] == 'yes'){
        //this is the code I want
    }
?>
<h1>you did not say yes <!-- There is an entire html page here in the real program-->                   

</h1>
```

I would like to make the following outputs occur

index.php?v=yes:

```
<h4>this text always shows</h4>
```

index.php?v=whatever

```
<h1>you did not say yes <!-- There is an entire html page here in the real program-->
<h4>this text always shows</h4>
```

Basically, I want a function that exits out of the current file (jumps to the end), but continues on with the file that included it.

Comment: Read the php docs. You can use return

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe. And I read the docs, I am just not very good at finding things in them.

Comment: Ok, Anyways you can also return values from include using return. 
like.
`$foo = include('bar.php'); // has what bar.php returns (return)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try putting your PHP codes AROUND your HTML codes like this:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['v'] != 'yes'){
?>
<!-- ENTER HTML CODE HERE -->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Completely forgot about this, but if you read the comments you would see that I already got an answer because this question was a duplicate. You still get an upvote though (from me) because this is very smart and would solve my situation.

Comment: Ahh, must have missed the comment when I was posting my answer, but thanks for the upvote! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

In `other-page.php` :

```
<?php
if($_GET['v'] != 'yes'){
    echo '<h1>You did not say yes.</h1>';
}
?>
```

Or have I misunderstood your question ? Basically you could just restructure the different block in order to avoid exiting.

Comment: You are misunderstanding, because in the full website (not going to post it here, way too huge). it is not just "you did not say yes", it is an entire ~500 line html page, something incredibly difficult to maintain when in an echo statment.

Comment: @john01dav also...  do not put a 500 or even 5 line html inside a echo... actully do not place html in your php.

Comment: The 500 line html file is what needs to be blocked from outputting when the condition is false. ALSO: it was a duplicate question so I got the answer. It is return;.

Comment: My answer basically says : if `if(true)` doesn't satisfy you, try using `if(false)` instead. Make sure you cannot change your code's structure (and you surely can, considering the fact that PHP scripts are not meant to be exited in common execution processes). Plus, you could put your HTML code between PHP tags (see aashnisshah's answer), or better : use a templating system such as Twig.

Comment: That is not applicable with my current code's more complex structure.